# Java LinkedList removing zero length members

Tags: java, arrays, string, linked-list

I am trying to remove members from a LinkedList whose length is zero. I am trying to make the code dynamic, where it removes all spaces from a String, yet leaving the words separate and in order. I try to accomplish this by converting a String into an array, and splitting it at the spaces. Then I convert it to a LinkedList for the purpose of my own preference.

```
private void sliceItUpFreashness() {
        String s = "    hello there"; // four spaces at beginning of string
        String[] sa = s.split(" ");
        LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(sa));

        for (int i = 0; i < ll.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Size for ll("+i+") == "+ll.get(i).length()); // confirms length of the members is 0
            if (ll.get(i).length() == 0) {
                ll.remove(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("-----");
        for (String a : ll) { // this confirms if the zero-length members were removed
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
```

However the above code doesn't remove the members with 0 or null length. What can I do?

Comment: Don't remove within a loop. Use `iterator` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you iterate the array once and build the `LinkedList` directly -

```
String s = "    hello there"; // four spaces at beginning of string
String[] sa = s.split(" ");
List<String> ll = new LinkedList<>();
for (String str : sa) {
  if (str.length() > 0) { // <-- check for empty string.
    ll.add(str);
  }
}
```

Another solution would be iterating on the String itself and skipping the `split`,

```
List<String> ll = new LinkedList<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) { // <-- String toCharArray
  if (ch != ' ') {
    sb.append(ch); // <-- not a space.
  } else {
    if (sb.length() > 0) { // <-- add non zero length strings to List
      ll.add(sb.toString());
      sb.setLength(0);
    }
  }
}
// Add the last of the buffer
if (sb.length() > 0) {
  ll.add(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. If I could up vote, I would. I'll vote as best as soon as the delay is up :)

Comment: @user3892311 you can acceept his answer

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively use `Collections.singleton("")`

```
    String s = "    hello there"; // four spaces at beginning of string
    String[] sa = s.split(" ");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sa));
    list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(""));
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not familiar with what the Collections.singleton does. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Collections.singleton returns an immutable set containing only the specified object. So I make a set containing empty string and then use remove all to remove from parent list.

Comment: In short that one line is similar to writing these 3 lines : `Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(); set.add(""); list.removeAll(set);`

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
String s = "    hello there"; // four spaces at beginning of string
    String[] sa = s.split(" ");
    LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(sa));

    ll.stream()
      .filter( s1 -> !s1.isEmpty())
      .map(s1-> s1)
      .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Ouput:

```
    hello there
hellothere
```

hope it helps and if you need more explantion pleas let me know

Note: I used Java 8 to solve this answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm running on java 7, so I don't understand the last four lines of code you posted. Could you explain them to me please :) ?

Comment: That is lamda expression introduced in java 8. Another thing to note is the `Stream` - "A sequence of elements supporting sequential and parallel aggregate operations." again introduced in Java 8. What that code does is it iterates over the list and filters out empty string, then get the result stream using the map and then again prints out each value using the forEach.